# Find $x^2 + y$ for the given conditions

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

Given $2^x-3y = 0$ and $3^x-2y = 0$, find the value of $x^2+y$.

I have tried taking logarithms and changing the base, expressing `x` and `y` in terms of each other, multiplying the equalities, but I always end up with something overly complicated or `0 = 0`.

Is there something obvious  that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\bigg(\frac{2}{3}\bigg)^{x}=\frac{2^{x}}{3^{x}}=\:?$$

Comment: Well, I guess division didn't look too obvious

Answer (score 1):

Note that: $$2^x = 3y = \frac32[2y] = \frac32[3^x] \implies \frac{2^x}{3^x} = \frac{3}{2} = \left(\frac23\right)^{-1}$$

Hence, $x=-1$ and hence, $y = \frac{1}{6}$.